# Embarcadero Cannot cast from 'UnicodeString' to 'unsigned char *'

Tags: c++, string, casting, c++builder, unicode-string

I'm using Embarcadero's C++ builder XE

```
String command1 = "FREQ ";
String command2 = " Mhz\n";
int index = Form1->ListBox1->ItemIndex;

String full = command1.operator +=(IntToStr((index+2)*10)).operator +=(command2);
TcpClient1->SendBuf((BYTE*)full,13,0);Sleep(30);
```

and on the last line I get
E2031 Cannot cast from 'UnicodeString' to 'unsigned char*'

What I'm sending is a command for my device (receiver) which format is (command, lenght_of_command). When I send it in plan text like

```
TcpClient1->SendBuf((BYTE*)"FREQ 330.5 MHz\n",15,0);Sleep(30);
```

everything is ok. Much thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use sprintf

```
char command[999];
sprintf(command, "FREQ %d MHz\n", (index+2)*10);
TcpClient1->SendBuf((BYTE*)command,strlen(command),0);
Sleep(30);
```

Comment: You are wasting well over 900 bytes that will never be used.  Either reduce the size of the array to a bare minimum length actually needed (21 max), or switch to `AnsiString` and use its `sprint()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`String` maps to `UnicodeString` in XE.  The simplest way to fix your code is to use `AnsiString` instead (and stop using the `+=` operator since you are not using it correctly):

```
AnsiString command1 = "FREQ ";
AnsiString command2 = " Mhz\n";
int index = Form1->ListBox1->ItemIndex;

AnsiString full = command1 + IntToStr((index+2)*10) + command2;
TcpClient1->SendBuf((BYTE*)full.c_str(),full.Length(),0);
Sleep(30);
```

Alternatively:

```
int index = Form1->ListBox1->ItemIndex;
AnsiString full;
full.sprintf("FREQ %d Mhz\n", (index+2)*10);
TcpClient1->SendBuf((BYTE*)full.c_str(),full.Length(),0);
Sleep(30);
```